# QList push_back object crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to push_back an instance of a c++ class to QList.

QList declared in the header file.

```
#include <QList>
#include "className.h"

QList<className> *items;
```

The QList is initialized in the constructor of the CPP file and deleted in the deconstructor.

In a member function, I declared the instance of className

```
void functionName()
{
    className item;
    item.set_name("name");

    items.push_back(item); // the app crashed once this code running
}
```

Then the app unexpected crash once it gets to the push_up function.

Any advice?

Comment: Your `items` is a pointer to a list. You need to allocate memory for it and initialize it. Otherwise you should define it like `QList<className> items;` instead.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] for your problem. _The QList is initialized in the constructor of the CPP file and deleted in the deconstructor._ What about the copy constructor? (Sounds like [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three) issue.)

Comment: Btw. with `QList<className> *items;`, the `items.push_back(item);` shouldn't even compile. (There is no raw pointer to anything which has a `push_back()` member function. Raw pointers don't have any member function.)

Comment: sorry I mean items->push_back. I also tried QList<className> items. crashes too

Comment: Please update your question: ensure that your example compiles and is a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the reason for dynamically using the pointer to allocate the memory when declaring the class. Once the objects are out of scope, the memory address is lost, thus the vector is not accessible.